# How to stream from OBS Studio onto ffserver?

Tags: streaming, ffserver, obs-studio

I have ffserver running and can send streams on it with:

```
ffmpeg -re -i intro.avi http://myserver:8090/feed1.ffm
```

I can do this from both windows and linux and it works.

Now I want to send the same stream with OBS Studio and failing.

Whenever format / codec I select, it immediately says

`An unspecified error occured while recording`

Log contains various errors like

```
Error opening 'http://myserver:8090/feed1.ffm': Invalid argument
ffmpeg_data_init failed
```

How to know what is wants and which argument is invalid?